# Word for a computer user without administrative access/privileges

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, epithet-requests

I'm looking for a suitable word to describe a computer application user, who has no administrator privileges.  To contextualize this, the application relates to the management of skills/abilities within a business environment, and this would be a level of access whereby a person could see their own data only.

The context is as follows:

```
Level  Term           Description
3      Super User     Highest level of access
2      Administrator  Medium/custom-level of access
1      ?????          Basic access
```

I found a [similar question here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/27769/what-is-a-good-name-for-non-administrator-users), but the context is different and therefore the suggestions are not appropriate.

Words that have been considered but deemed unsuitable are:

- **User** - too general, and a Super User and Administrator are also "users", so this was confusing
- **Basic** - not contextual enough, and maybe construed as relating to "stupid"
- **Standard** - not contextual enough
- **Student** - the software is not academic, and this relates too closely to education
- **General** - best so far

Comment: Why is user too general? typically, the higher levels encompass the lower ones. A Super User probably has the same rights as an Administrator, *and then some*, right? and he probably also has the rights a normal user also has.

Comment: Some people feel that there isn't enough differentiation.  I know its opinion-based, so was reaching out for other possibilities to compare against.

Comment: It's user. All users are users, but some have special privileges - like the super user.

Comment: If you relax the single-word requirement (as is the case for _Super User_) then combining your first two considerations would be my suggestion: **Basic User**.

Comment: Windows, Linux and MacOS use 'standard user' and 'administrator'.

Comment: Have you checked the definitions of the various terms? Let us know what you found.

Comment: @Kris: IT terminologies are conventions at best, not standards. There is no objective measure of the correctness of most terms (unless we're referring to the terminologies employed by a specific company). In the best case scenario, the OP can find _common_ usages, but not necessarily _objectively correct_ usages (as correctness is not defined purely by being used more often).

Comment: @Flater All the same, homework is almost a prerequisite on ELU.

Comment: @Kris You can't do homework on a topic that doesn't exist. It's also nigh impossible to prove their non-existence (as you can't prove a negative) There is no resource that accurately describes IT terminologies (in a global sense, not the limited scope of e.g. a single company or application). Also, any question that is posted here can be solved by the poster by doing sufficient homework. The point of this question is that the OP can't see the wood for the trees, as he lists potential candidates (= homework) but cannot decide on which is the most accurate.

Comment: The reason it’s called a super user, is because ’user’ came first.

Comment: @Jim: Your point being? Not implying there isn't any point, just that I'm not quite following as to how it relates to the question at hand.

Comment: @Polygnome _User_ is too generic for precisely the reason you give: admins and super users are also users and also have all the rights that basic/standard users have, so it’s confusing to use _user_ on its own to refer to a group that specifically excludes admins and super users. It’s kind of like using _royalty_ to specifically describe members of the royal family who aren’t currently monarchs regnant, or (to take an example that did actually occur in Germanic languages) to use _man_ to refer exclusively to humans who are male, excluding the other half.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet All cows are animals. Not all Animals are cows. All admins are also users, but not all users are admins. So I do not see the problem in calling the lowest of your types "user" and use more specialized names for more special roles (that nonethless encompass the lower roles). Super User ⊆ Admin ⊆ User, isn't it?

Comment: @Polygnome And if someone asked “What do you call any animal that is **not** a cow?”, would you consider _animal_ an accurate answer? Would you consider, “No, that’s not an animal; it’s a cow” or “That’s a cow; it’s not an animal” to make sense? Ignoring the fact that I don’t think there is a word that encompasses all animals except cows, that seems wildly inaccurate to me. Using a generic word for a broad category to refer specifically to one particular subsection of that same category, excluding other subsections, is exceedingly likely to cause confusion.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But an administrator *is* a user, isn't he? And your levels form a hierachy. In any hierachy I have ever seen the most all-encompassing term is always used for the bottom layer, and from there on more specialized terms are used. To me, your objections only make sense if Administrators *weren't* also users, which they most likely are (or is there a subset of features that users have access to, but Administrators don't have access to? in that case, your objection makes sense).

Comment: @Polygnome Exactly. If admins and super users _weren’t_ users, it would make sense to use _user_ here, but because they are, it doesn’t. I have to admit I have never come across a hierarchy that worked like what you’re describing. Take [US Army ranks](https://www.infoplease.com/us/military-personnel/us-military-ranks) as an example. The most basic level there is (as far as I can tell) _private_, but a major general or second lieutenant is not also a subtype of private. It’s arguably a subtype of _soldier_, but the term for an entry-level soldier is not _soldier_. That would be confusing. The →

Comment: → definition of _soldier_ would end up being, “A soldier is a soldier who has not advanced beyond the entry-level army rank”. Similarly here, the definition of a _user_ would end up being, “A user is a user who does not have admin or super user rights”. How would you tell whether you’re using _user_ to refer to any user (including admins and super users) or to refer to any user (excluding admins and super users)? You’d have to rely entirely on context, which would frequently make it unclear and confusing what you’re talking about.

Comment: I came across some old definitions. Users: Collective term for those who stare vacantly at a monitor.  Users are divided into three types: novice, intermediate, and expert.  Novice users: People who are afraid that simply pressing a key might break their computer.  Intermediate users: People who don't know how to fix their computer after they've just pressed a key that broke it.  Expert users: People who break other people's computers.  That would probably make the answer "novice" or "intermediate".  Hope this guidance helps.

Comment: A user uses, an administrator administrates, and a super-user is somewhere in between. Perfectly simple. In many systems, someone responsible for system administration may actually have two accounts or log-ins, one for when they want to use the system and one when they must perform specific administrative tasks.

Answer (score 8):

This is often called an *unprivileged* user.

The Linux man page for [user_namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/user_namespaces.7.html) starts:

> User namespaces isolate security-related identifiers and attributes,
>          in particular, user IDs and group IDs (see credentials(7)), the root
>          directory, keys (see keyrings(7)), and capabilities (see
>          capabilities(7)).  A process's user and group IDs can be different
>          inside and outside a user namespace.  In particular, a process can
>          have a normal **unprivileged user** ID outside a user namespace while at
>          the same time having a user ID of 0 inside the namespace; in other
>          words, the process has full privileges for operations inside the user
>          namespace, but is unprivileged for operations outside the namespace.

Microsoft's [security best practices](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/implementing-least-privilege-administrative-models) include headers that use similar terms:

> Creating **Unprivileged Accounts** to Manage Privileged Accounts

Apple refers to unprivileged applications in [security bulletins](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202854):

> By registering for a hotkey event, an **unprivileged** application could log keystrokes entered into other applications even when secure input mode was enabled. This issue was addressed by additional validation of hotkey events.

Answer (score 6):

As is the case with many IT related terminologies, there is room for interpretation here. There is no established ruleset specific to IT. Though *conventions* may exists, they are not yet implemented to a level of anything non-conventional being considered flatout incorrect.

### Some feedback on your ideas

> **User** - too general, and a Super User and Administrator are also "users", so this was confusing

I disagree here. "User" is perfect. If I say the following:

> The party was attended by employees and managers alike.

A manager is still a (type of) employee!

Similarly, just because an administrator is inherently a user, does not preclude the common inference that when you say "user", you mean "those who are **only** users".
Though you are correct that that is not *explicitly* stated, it is a fairly obvious implication, often made even clearer by the surrounding context in which it is used.

I honestly think "user" is the best answer here.

> **Basic** - not contextual enough, and maybe construed as relating to "stupid"

[OED link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/basic)

*"Common to or required by everyone; primary and ineradicable or inalienable."*

According to IT, everyone is a user. It literally means "anyone who is using a computer" (or other device). Therefore, "basic user" is applicable.

I don't agree with your notion of "basic user" implying a **stupid** user. If you were to say "simple user", however, I do think that inference can possibly be made.

> **Standard** - not contextual enough

In my opinion, it is contextual enough. However, consider using "default" over "standard", as it is slightly more common in the field of IT.

> **Student** - The software is not academic, relates too closely to education

I agree, this is not relevant.

> **General** - best so far

I don't agree. "general" is way too broad. Also, consider the definition of the word "general":

[OED link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/general)

*"Affecting or concerning all or most people or things; widespread."*

"General" means "the most **common**", not "the most basic". If you have a company where there are more administrators than normal users, then administrators can be considered to be the general users.

### Some additions from me

> **Default** users

Relatively similar to "standard", meaning that this type of user is the *entry point* for users. "Default" seems more common in the context of IT, compared to "standard".

> **Generic** users

This suggestion again relies on the idea that administrators are still part of the group of users. They are a **subset**, not a separate group, and that distinction is incredibly important in the field of IT.

[OED link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/generic)

*"Characteristic of, or relating to a class or group of things; not specific."*

In your case, "generic user" means "any type of user". It is logically implied that when many types of users are addressed at the same time, that you are expected to treat them by their **common denominator**.

Logically speaking, the most common denominator of "all users" is equal to "the most basic level of user".

> A user (**who is not an Administrator**)
>   A user (**who has no elevated rights**)

This suggestion is based on your specific context.

In my experience as a software developer, this is very common in documentation regarding the security access. This can be extended to describing the visibility of information, your specific scenario.

Keep in mind that such documentation is often read by IT personnel, who are logically minded. A logical inversion ("not having X") is more clear than the addition of another defined role.

When you use a named definition (e.g. standard user), you allow for the implication that a "standard user" is an established (explicitly named) role. You can avoid such an unintended implication by using a logical inversion that describes what you mean.

### Conclusion

Other than "student", every option listed here is valid. The issues you bring forward are not necessarily incorrect, but I do consider them nitpicky; I highly doubt that people will focus in the inherent meaning of the word rather than the meaning you're trying to convey.

However, as "user" conveys the correct meaning here, it seems superfluous to have add a further description. In the interest of brevity where it doesn't affect the clarity of the message, I advocate simply using "user".

As a general rule for IT, especially in the case of clear communication, I would suggest you adhere to the following:

> Where possible, always avoid using **named** **definitions**, if an accurate **description** can be used in its place.

Names can change more easily than descriptions.

Comment: Given that these basic users (that is by far the best option in my view) are actually explicitly contrasted with super users, I disagree that _user_ by itself is good. In your parallel example, it would be like saying that the party was attended by employees and senior employees alike—awkward and not intuitive. There is also the difference that _employee_ has an inherent aspect of ‘non-executive’, which _user_ doesn’t. To call an managing director an employee may not be formally inaccurate, but it would sound strange to most; conversely, calling an admin a user is quite normal.

Comment: Also, _default users_ is similar to _general users_ (and _generic users_) in that it does not specifically say that these are entry-level users with no special rights. In a system where all users are made administrators by default (and must be manually demoted to have admin rights taken away from them), administrators would be default users too. It probably works in most cases, but not everywhere.

Comment: I think that "default user" is misleading, because "default" usually refers to the option you use when no other choice has been made.  In other words, its their role, or their privileges, that are default, not the user themselves.  I'd favour "standard" or "regular" personally.

Comment: @MaxWilliams "the option you use when no other choice has been made" that's sort of the reason why I'm arguing that it's valid. It is the default user state (in regards to rights) that any user starts off with. Further rights will only be granted when needed, and that will be evaluated on a case by case basis (therefore they are not default)

Comment: @Flater "default user **state**" is fine, but "default *user*" sounds like a completely different thing - it sounds like you're talking about a specific user account which you use as a default somewhere.  Like "Which user did you use with the tests?  Oh just the default user."

Comment: @MaxWilliams: While I agree with your specific example, I do think that using the singular adds a considerable implication. "The default user" inherently states that the default option is limited to a single user.

Comment: @Flater I disagree. I don't think it "inherently states" anything, I think it's an ambiguous term that could be interpreted differently, and I think a lot of people would **not** interpret it as meaning "the default role or permissions of a user account", which is what the question is asking about.

Comment: @MaxWilliams. "The default weapon for soldiers" inherently states that the default weapon for a soldier is always the same (type of) weapon (e.g. a rifle), whereas "The default weapons for soldiers" could list many (a default rifle, a default machinegun, a default pistol, ...) that the soldier can still (freely) choose from. But when you use the singular, you explicitly denote that the default is limited to a singular option and therefore logically imply that no choice can be made. "Default users" inherently implies that the default is not limited to a single (fixed) user.